# Using functools.wraps function with a little bit different argument list

Tags: python, decorator, functools, strawberry-graphql

I want to do something like this:

```
def need_session(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        session = SessionLocal()
        try:
            func(session, *args, **kwargs)
        finally:
            session.close()
```

I'm using the `wraps` function, because I'm using [Strawberry](https://pypi.org/project/strawberry-graphql/), which depends on argument types.

As you can see, `func` is given an extra `session` argument.

How can I make this work?

If I try to run a GraphQL server using Strawberry that has functions that are decorated using the decorator above, it gives me this error:

> TypeError: Mutation fields cannot be resolved. Unexpected type '<class 'sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session'>'

If I change the decorator to this:

```
def need_session(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        session = SessionLocal()
        kwargs['session'] = session
        try:
            func(*args, **kwargs)
        finally:
            session.close()
```

And change the decorated function's argument list to:

```
def some_func(some_arg: SomeClass, **kwargs):
    ...
```

I still get this error:

> strawberry.exceptions.MissingArgumentsAnnotationsError: Missing annotation for argument "kwargs" in field "login_user", did you forget to add it?

Comment: Please show a [complete](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146) error message and a [mre].

Comment: You probably need to return the function from the decorator at some point...

Answer (score 1):

##### Why the *error*?

You get this exception because Strawberry doesn't support `**kwargs` and every `strawberry.field` must have annotations for all arguments. And they are processed by the `strawberry.type` decorator, so you can’t modify the function signature.

##### Possible solution 1:

You can provide the session inside the Strawberry `Info` by writing a schema extension.

Example:

```py
from strawberry.extensions import Extension
from mydb import get_db_session


class DbSessionMiddleWare(Extension):
    def on_request_start(self):
        self.execution_context.context["db"] = get_db_session()

    def on_request_end(self):
        self.execution_context.context["db"].close()

schema = strawberry.Schema(
    query=Queries,
    mutation=Mutations,
    extensions=[
        DbSessionMiddleWare,
    ],
)
```

Some resolver:

```py
from strawberry.types import Info


def resolve_name(info: Info):
    name = info.context['db'].execute("SELECT ...")
```

---

##### Possible solution 2:

You can wrap Strawberry decorators with your own decorator and inject some annotations as you wish. 
Remember that you should clear any `*args` or `**kwargs` from the function signature other ways strawberry would complain about this.

Example:

```py
from strawberry.arguments import StrawberryArgument, StrawberryAnnotation, UNSET
import inspect

def create_strawberry_argument(
    python_name: str, graphql_name: str, type_, default=None
):
    return StrawberryArgument(
        python_name=python_name,
        graphql_name=graphql_name,
        type_annotation=StrawberryAnnotation(type_),
        default=default or UNSET,
    )

def hide_args_kwargs(field):

    sig = inspect.signature(field)
    cleared = tuple(
        p for p in sig.parameters.values() if p.name not in ("kwargs", "args")
    )
    field.__signature__ = inspect.signature(field).replace(parameters=(cleared))
    return field

def inject_mutation(field, arguments: tuple[str, type]):
    field = hide_args_kwargs(field)
    field = strawberry.mutation(field, description=field.__doc__)
    for arg_tuple in arguments:
        arg = create_strawberry_argument(arg_tuple[0], arg_tuple[0], arg_tuple[1])
        field.arguments.append(arg)
    return field

@inject_mutation(('arg2', int))
def some_resolver(info, arg1, **kwargs) -> SomeOutputType:
    f = kwargs.get('arg2', None)
```

Comment: Thanks for giving the explanation - to me this whole decorator based approach in strawberry seems to me very *unpythonic* because a lot of stuff happens implicit in the background, there is no IDE support and you can not interfere with it in a trivial manner. Do you have any insights what the advantages of such an approach are?

Comment: 1. clean syntax.
2. dataclasses style.
3. simpler for developers (instaed of using metaclasses hacks). BTW there is IDE support for both PyCharm and VS code. @capitalg of course there is a price that it is less flexible user wise..

Comment: After working some weeks with strawberry now I think its decorator based approach is its biggest weakness, at least it gives me lots of frustration - its not really a dataclass as there is logic inside and the example above shows that a class is much more easy to inspect, handle, debug and modify than a decorator/function. It is also unclear what happens behind the curtains without reading closely the source code as inspection of a function/object is much more limited at "compile"time than that of a class, so I think the IDE support is indeed non existent

Comment: @capitalg I totally agree and I have tried in my PR to move to more class driven approuch though it is not about to be merged any time soon... Ref: https://github.com/strawberry-graphql/strawberry/pull/2117

Comment: And IDE support - https://strawberry.rocks/docs/editors/vscode#install-pylance